# missed signal in c++11 condition variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a small doubt about thread being woken up and unavailability of the lock

```
std::mutex mut; 
std::queue<data_chunk> data_queue;   
std::condition_variable data_cond;

void data_preparation_thread() {    
    while(more_data_to_prepare())    {        
        data_chunk const data=prepare_data();        
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);        
        data_queue.push(data);                      
        data_cond.notify_one(); //mutex is still locked here      
    }
}

void data_processing_thread() {
    while(true)    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut); 
        data_cond.wait(lk,[]{return !data_queue.empty();}); //what if lk could not acquire the mutex.
        data_chunk data=data_queue.front();        
        data_queue.pop();        
        lk.unlock();
        process(data);
        if(is_last_chunk(data))
            break;
    }
```

}

In the above example data_preparation_thread() puts data in the queue and notifies and thread waiting on the condition_variable.

My question, if the other thread wakes up and finds the associated mutex is still not available, it sleeps again. Isn't it a condition of missed signal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if the other thread wakes up and finds the associated mutex is still not available, it sleeps again

Once it re-acquires the mutex it proceeds to test the condition.

Condition variable notification is essentially a hint that the condition may have changed and needs to be re-evaluated. There can be [spurious wake-ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). The code waits for the condition to become true, not for the signal.

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between "sleeping" on the condition variable (i.e. waiting for a signal) and "sleeping" on the mutex (i.e. waiting to lock it).

If the thread wakes up from waiting on the condition variable and the mutex is still locked it starts waiting on the mutex, until it can acquire it and then check the *condition* (i.e. the predicate). That's not the same as waiting on the condvar again, so nothing has been missed. It's still waiting to check if the condition is true, which it can't do until it acquires the mutex lock.

Assuming that you correctly check the condition when waking (which is what the predicate you pass to `condition_variable::wait` does) then you won't miss the event that caused the signal.